# VBA error 9 can't find the solution

Tags: vba, excel

I have read plenty of articles here on runtime error 9 but didn't manage to understand how it applied to my case. I'm also very new to VBA so apologies if this has to do with the basics...

Anyways, I'm trying to copy range("A39:D39") to the next available row in one of three tables in another sheet. Which table (not specifically formatted as a table by the way) depends on the input that the user has given in the Listbox.

Here is my code:

```
Sub ListBoxValue_Method3()

    Worksheets("Calculations").Activate

     Dim lbValue As Integer

    lbValue = Worksheets("Calculations").ListBoxes("List Box 8").Value

    Worksheets("Calculations").Range("A39:D39").Copy


Select Case lbValue

    Case 1

    Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Case 2

    Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues   %%%%%ERROR HERE%%%%%

    Case 3

    Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Case Else

    MsgBox ("Check input")

End Select


End Sub
```

The error is:

```
Run-time error '9':

Subscript out of range
```

I'm using Excel 2016 (365).
Thanks in advance to anyone who is willing to take the time to have a look.

Comment: Does the Error only accure in case 2?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't depend on which menu item is selected in the Listbox because I have tried changing it, and it still gives the error at that spot.

Comment: When the error occurs next time, click OK, then hit Ctrl+G to get the Immediate Window. In that window, put this: `? Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Address` and show us what the output is.

Comment: However now the error is:

Run-time error '438':

Object doesn't support this property or method

This error occurs at the paste command.

Comment: Ignore the comment before.

Immediate window doesn't seem available on Mac. Same problem still occurs as stated in OP.

Comment: Just a guess (no way to test it), but "List Box 8" is likely not the correct index.  It looks like the `Caption` of the control, not the `Name`.  No way to tell without checking the properties, but I suspect you need "ListBox8" as the index.

Answer (score 0):

you seem to use MAC, which I don't.

but you could give this code a try

```
Sub ListBoxValue_Method3()
    Dim lbValue As Integer

    With Worksheets("Calculations")
        lbValue = .OLEObjects("List Box 8").Object.value

        With .Range("A39:D39")
            Select Case lbValue
                Case 1
                    Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).offset(1, 0).Resize(, .Columns.Count).value = .value
                Case 2
                    Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).offset(1, 0).Resize(, .Columns.Count).value = .value
                Case 3
                    Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).offset(1, 0).Resize(, .Columns.Count).value = .value
                Case Else
                    MsgBox ("Check input")
            End Select
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

where I assumed your "List Box 8" listbox is an "ActiveX" one

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, I used a Form Control. Is that wrong?

Comment: ActiveX Controls are apparently not possible on Mac I just realised.

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure the name of the sheet is correct -.-'

Code was fine, just an inexistent Worksheet.

How missing the simplest things can take ages to realise!